# How do you align text on a Text Field?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I made a `TextField` using Libgdx scene2d and I want the text on the text field to appear on the center, so when the user type a string, the string will start at the center and not at the left. I also tried to set the cursor position but nothing is happening, is it because it's in a table?

```
textField = new TextField("", tfStyle);
textField.setCursorPosition(33);
table.add(tf);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `textField.setAlignment(Align.center);`.

> setAlignment(int alignment)
>
> Sets text horizontal alignment (left, center or right).